# Limit with B-smooth function

Tags: limits, prime-factorization

I have a question about limits with factorization functions.

> Prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\log  L(\sqrt{N})}{\log 
> > L(N)^{1/\sqrt{2}}}=1$, where $L(N)=e^{\sqrt{(\ln  N)(\ln  \ln  N)}}$.

I have gone about this in many ways; L'Hopital's rule, changing the base, rearranging the exponents, etc, but cannot find a solution. Can you give any hints?

Comment: Your $L(x)$ has nothing to do with $x$. Is it a typo?

Comment: @CaveJohnson I guess the OP means $N\to\infty$ instead of $x\to\infty$. Or $x$ instead of $N$ in the formula in the limit...

Comment: Yes thank you, it was meant to be $N$ to infinity.